# How can I set-up properly query to get specific result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I need to do 2 reports from table I am showing below.

1. I need one report to see all kids that are still in school in the moment of executing report
2. I need one report to give me number of hours for each kid spent in school. For kids that are still in school number of hours when they enter school and current time.

Can you help me to properly set logic for those two cases?

Detailed explanation:

- For example John started from House and go to School at some moment, than after several minutes he goes to Library (School -> Library). Again after some time he goes from (Library -> School) again and at end he goes from (School -> House). The other guys are the same story.
- Now I have trouble to set logic to get those 2 cases and to set up queries properly.

Thanks in advance :)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #temp
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp 
(
    Person nvarchar(max), 
    src_location nvarchar(max),  
    dst_location nvarchar(max), 
    [time] datetime 
)
GO

INSERT INTO #temp (person, src_location, dst_location, time) 
VALUES ('John', 'House', 'School', '2018-08-31 08:53:55'),
       ('Peter', 'House', 'School', '2018-08-31 09:01:55'),
       ('John', 'School', 'Library', '2018-08-31 09:03:14'),
       ('Tina', 'Park', 'School', '2018-08-31 09:10:22'),
       ('John', 'Library', 'School', '2018-08-31 09:50:14'),
       ('John', 'School', 'House', '2018-08-31 00:48:14'),
       ('Tina', 'School', 'House', '2018-08-31 00:15:22'),
       ('John', 'House', 'School', '2018-10-16 08:22:32')

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not that proficient in MSSQL. A general way to tackle your first question would be to query for the latest entry per user (GROUP BY [person]) and then filtering them for persons having dst_location equal to School ([dst_location] = 'School')

I see that this does not work completely as it still returns Tina, while she has left school already, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b1c8/24

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution for first case:

Table with all informations bellow:

```
Person      src_location         dst_location              time                   
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- -----------------------
John        House                School                    2018-08-31 08:53:55.000
Peter       House                School                    2018-08-31 09:01:55.000
John        School               Library                   2018-08-31 09:03:14.000
Tina        Park                 School                    2018-08-31 09:10:22.000
John        Library              School                    2018-08-31 09:50:14.000
John        School               House                     2018-08-31 00:48:14.000
Tina        School               House                     2018-08-31 11:15:22.000
John        House                School                    2018-10-16 08:22:32.000
```

Partitions by 'person' and ordered by 'time' desc and get the first result (because of order by time dsc in out case those are the last results for each person).

```
  WITH KidsAtSchool AS (
SELECT m.person, 
       m.src_location,
       m.dst_location,
       m.time,
       DATEDIFF(day, [time], GETDATE()) AS HoursAtSchool,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY time DESC) AS rn
  FROM #temp AS m
)

SELECT *
  FROM KidsAtSchool
 WHERE rn = 1 
   AND dst_location = 'School'
```

Results I got are correct :)

```
Person      src_location         dst_location              time                    HoursAtSchool  
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ----------------------- --------------
John        House                School                    2018-10-16 08:22:32.000   661
Peter       House                School                    2018-08-31 09:01:55.000   707
```

If you still find a better way or query that execute faster (since this one is quite slow), I would appreciate reading your answer.

Also, the second case is still hard for me.

Comment: you need do achieve it with a query or can do a stored procedure?

Comment: @Alrik It can be Stored Procedure, why not. Whatever works :)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try:

```
DECLARE @person nvarchar(50), @location nvarchar(50),  
@time datetime, @permanence int, @enters datetime, @exits datetime,
@inside int, @person_sv nvarchar(50);  

SET @inside = 0
DECLARE school CURSOR FOR   
SELECT person, dst_location, time  
FROM #temp  
ORDER BY person, time DESC;  

OPEN school  

SET @person_sv = ''

FETCH NEXT FROM school   
INTO @person, @location, @time  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
     IF @person <> @person_sv -- person changed, we had the time!
     BEGIN
         IF @permanence <> 0 -- only person who had been at school
         BEGIN
             IF @location = 'School' -- last location for person, he/she is still in
             BEGIN
                 @permanence += DATEDIFF(h, @enters, GETDATE()
             END
             INSERT INTO #temp2 VALUES (@person_sv, @permanence)
         END 
         SET @person_sv = @person
         SET @permanence = 0
     END
     IF @location = 'School' -- person enters
     BEGIN
         IF @inside = 0 -- person is not in school
         BEGIN
             set @enters = @time
             set @inside = 1 -- now person is in
         END
     END 
     IF @location <> 'School'
     BEGIN
         IF @inside = 1 -- person is in school
         BEGIN
             set @exits = @time
             set @permanence += DATEDIFF(day, @enters, @exits)
             set @inside = 0 -- person had exited
         END
     END 

FETCH NEXT FROM school   
INTO @person, @location, @time  
END   
CLOSE school;  
DEALLOCATE school;
```

Does not have tried it, sorry but i'm out of work :)